# Paypal REST API SDK - Activating a billing plan in C#

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have the following code to create a billing plan

```
 string iClientID = "xxxxxx";
        string iSecret = "yyyyyy";

        Dictionary<string, string> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        sdkConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");
        string accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(iClientID, iSecret, sdkConfig).GetAccessToken();
    APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
    apiContext.Config = sdkConfig;

    Plan xPlan = new Plan();
    xPlan.name = "Billing Plan OneA";
    xPlan.description = "Our first billing plan for testing";
    xPlan.type = "INFINITE";

    PaymentDefinition xPDef = new PaymentDefinition();
    xPDef.name = "Payment Def One";
    xPDef.type = "REGULAR";
    xPDef.frequency_interval = "1";
    xPDef.frequency = "MONTH";
    xPDef.cycles = "0";

    MerchantPreferences xPrefs = new MerchantPreferences();
    xPrefs.cancel_url = "http://learnoogle.com";
    xPrefs.return_url = "http://learnoogle.com?success";


    Currency xPCUrr = new Currency();
    xPCUrr.currency = "USD";
    xPCUrr.value = "25.00";

    xPDef.amount = xPCUrr;

    List<PaymentDefinition> xDeffs = new List<PaymentDefinition>();
    xDeffs.Add(xPDef);

    xPlan.payment_definitions = xDeffs;
    xPlan.merchant_preferences = xPrefs;
        Plan cPLan = xPlan.Create(apiContext);
```

And I attempt to set the plan active with the following code

```
    Patch xPatch = new Patch();
    xPatch.op = "replace";
    xPatch.path = "state";
    xPatch.value = "ACTIVE";

    PatchRequest yPatch = new PatchRequest();
    yPatch.Add(xPatch);

    cPLan.Update(apiContext, yPatch);
```

However this gives me a (400) Bad Request.
{"name":"BUSINESS_VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"validation_error","issue":"Invalid Path provided."}],"message":"Validation Error.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#BUSINESS_VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"01f0eb9aaaea0"}

Can anyone educate me on what I am doing wrong on this/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When updating a plan, you'll need to set the `Patch.value` property to a new `Plan` object containing the fields you'd like to replace (setting the `state` to `ACTIVE` in this case).  Also, you'll need to set the `Patch.path` property to just `"/"`.

In your code, do the following:

```
Patch xPatch = new Patch();
xPatch.op = "replace";
xPatch.path = "/";
xPatch.value = new Plan() { state = "ACTIVE" };

PatchRequest yPatch = new PatchRequest();
yPatch.Add(xPatch);

cPLan.Update(apiContext, yPatch);
```

Comment: Thank you - paypal dev docs didnt make this very clear - i found i could parse a json string into a json object with Newtonsoft and do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the code has changed since the approved answer was submitted. It should now be something like this:

```
var client = new PayPalHttpClient(environment);
JsonPatch<Plan> xPatch = new JsonPatch<Plan>();
xPatch.op = "replace";
xPatch.path = "/";
xPatch.value = new Plan() { state = "ACTIVE" };

PlanUpdateRequest<Plan> yPatch = new PlanUpdateRequest<Plan>(planId);
yPatch.RequestBody(new List<JsonPatch<Plan>>() { patch });

BraintreeHttp.HttpResponse response = client.Execute(yPatch).Result; // or await this
```